# Licensing an image and artwork

Tags: copyright, licensing, music, photography

A musician asked me to create his latest album cover off one of my photographs.

He's not famous and will only publish his work on a few music websites, so he will use the artwork as a digital file only. I want to grant him the sole rights to do this. In other words he would become the only owner of the photograph and the album artwork created.

If, one day, his album would be physically published, ie. as a vinyl, or if he would want to sell products derived from it, we would then discuss a separate license and fee.

- Do I need separate licenses, 1 for the photograph and 1 for the artwork?
- What license type would be acceptable for such a use case?

Let me know if anything needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Do I need separate licenses, 1 for the photograph and 1 for the artwork?

You don’t “need” 2 licences but given that you haven’t agreed the terms of physical publication it might be more practical.

> - What license type would be acceptable for such a use case?

One that sets out the rights and obligations of each party in sufficient detail that disputes are unlikely. On that point, a dispute resolution clause might also be a good idea.

Comment: Right. Yes, I understand now that my question wasn't detailed enough. I was expecting to find a ready template in which I would just fill in the info but that seems difficult so I will try to come up with my own license, detailing our needs.